# What are AKT(algorithm knowledgeable for tree) algorithm in real life?

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, decision-tree

I know what AKT dose, and I know a some puzzle game that use this algorithm to solve, for example: sudoku, sliding puzzle, tic-tac-toe, specifically here they use decision tree to and compute a heuristic function. I mean what do they use AKT algorithm in real life.